# Como puedo validar cuando mi tabla cuenta con un registro nuevo o cuando cuenta con los mismos registros

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando un proyecto en donde una linea de producción registra sus pallets desde una tablet.

Donde estoy atorado y por más que investigo no encuento solucion es que necesito detectar desde mi tabla cuando alguien ya registro un pallet me reste 1 en caso contrario si ningun operador a registrado un pallet sin importar cuantos registros tenga mi tabla me sume 1 cada cierto tiempo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! suena a que necesitas un trigger y ademas un cron para ejecutar un sp de vez en cuando...

Comment: Eso es, pásanos un dataset o algo que podamos ver y probar... así como tus intentos por resolverlo